# When Dolphin finds a file, what is the path to that file?

Tags: paths, dolphin

When Dolphin finds a file, it does not indicate the path to that file. How can I find out what that path is?

Answer (score 0):

**1° Alternative**

- Perform a "right click" on file finded list and select "Properties".
- See the location path inside "General" tab. 
  [image: awesome ImpScr]

**2° Alternative**

- Inside Dolphin window, select the "Detailed View" option 
  [image: nother awesome ss]
- In those columns, you can add the "path" column performing a right click on "name (Nombre)" column and select "Other (Otro)".
- For finally mark "Path (Ruta)" option =) !
- Here we are: 
  [image]

Spanish interface for learning =) !